# Transaction Check Error при установке MySQL

Tags: mysql

При установке MsQl вот такая штука. Что делать?

> `Transaction Check Error:
>   file /usr/bin/mysql from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqladmin from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqldump from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqlimport from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/bin/mysqlshow from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386
>   file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.0.92-1.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package MySQL-client-5.5.10-1.rhel5.i386`
>
> `Error Summary`

Comment: Откуда скачивали?
Какая ОСь?
Какие права?

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые версии MySQL конфликтуют друг с другом, да и в принципе зачем они обе нужны...